# Extract words based on a pattern in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

Since I couldn't find enough resources on how to extract a string based on pattern in **groovy**, I am posting this question and would sincerely appreciate your input.

If I have a String as

```
concept:athlete:eddie_mathews
```

How can I extract the first and 2nd terms based on the colon, `:`, i.e. I need to only extract the following.

- athlete
- eddie_mathews

I already have the above string as shown below.

```
fullArray[3][1] = "concept:athlete:eddie_mathews"
```

Then I need to get the following

```
def term1 = athlete
def term2 = eddie_mathews
```